# Calling a function which returns several values

Tags: javascript

If a function returns more than one calculation and it's convenient to reuse that one function in few separate instances, is it best to store the result of the calculations in an internal array and just pull out of the array a calculation that's needed on that particular call or is there a more efficient way?

```
var calcFunction = function() {

    var ar = [];

    var calcA = ...
    ar.push(calcA);

    var calcB = ...
    ar.push(calcA);

    return ar;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are options off the top of my head in order of my preference. Performance, if truly releavant, you should benchmark. Preference depends on your code and its purpose.

```
        // If independent and appropriate, split it into two separate functions
        // modularization into smaller reusable building blocks is good
        var calcAFunction = function() {
          var calcA = ...
          return calcA;
        }

        var calcBFunction = function() {
          var calcB = ...
          return calcB;
        }

        // Returning an array
        var calcFunction = function() {

          var ar = [];

          var calcA = ...
          ar.push(calcA);

          var calcB = ...
          ar.push(calcA);

          return ar;

        }
        // Returning an object, disadvantage you must maintain key names as opposed to index 
        var calcFunction = function() {

          var o = {};

          var calcA = ...
          o.key1 = calcA;

          var calcB = ...
          o["key2"] = calcB;

          return o;

        }
        // Calling it with a callback function
        var calcFunction = function(cb) {

          var o = {};

          var calcA = ...

          var calcB = ...

          cb(calcA, calcB)

        }
        calcFunction(function(A, B) {})
```

UPDATE

```
        // Returning an object, disadvantage you must maintain key names as opposed to index 
        var calcFunction = function() {

          var o = {};

          var calcA = ...
          o.key1 = calcA;

          var calcB = ...
          o["key2"] = calcB;

          return o;

        }

        var retObj = calcFunction();
        //you can access retObj.key1 and retObj.key2
```

Comment: How do I call this if it's the `o["key2"] = calcB;` way and I need the calcB value?

Comment: @user3101259 I just added that to show you two ways you can set a key on an object. you can access that from the return object as _o.key2_ or _o.["key2"]_. The latter syntax is useful when you have spaces in your key name for example _o.["with space"]_ (_o.with space_ won't work obviously)

Comment: I mean the whole line.. `var foo = calcFunction(o.["key2"]);` ?

Comment: @user3101259 is the UPDATE what you mean up top?

Answer (score 2):

If you're function is really long, it'll be much more efficient to use the array every time, however, this distance gets shorter and shorter as the function gets shorter. However, this isn't the only reason to use the array. Calling the function several times with the same values is essentially code duplication, which is a standard code smell.

Overall, if you can call a method as few times as possible, you've done your job right.